# MMSE editing policy

Tags: discussion, policies, editing, low-rep-users

Unfortunately, all edits on questions or answers lead to the question being bumped to the top of the front page. This is something that happens across the Stack Exchange network, and MMSE has no control over it. "[Some people are irritated to re-open a post of interest to find one minute change](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2814/211119)." This issue is compounded and made substantially worse when a user makes ***multiple*** such edits within a short time span.

One of our missions at MMSE is to help users get answers to their questions. Bumping up an ***answered*** question just to change a tag, or to correct a minor spelling mistake (or formatting mistake or grammatical mistake) causes the answered question to get bumped ahead of unanswered questions. This means that a question for which we have already accomplished the above mission, is stealing from questions for which we have not yet accomplished the above mission.

Also, even if a question does not have an answer, in general we have been rejecting ***suggested*** edits when they are deemed to be too minor. The same happens at Stack Overflow, Parenting.SE, and other sites within the SE network (I can provide examples if it's requested).